# Server lost its property

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

My Node.JS HTTP server handles a GET request with JSON query by invoking `runNextMethod`. This function gets `url_parsed.query` as argument.

```
function runNextMethod(query)
{
    if(nextMethodIndex<methodOrder.length)
    {
         var func = myDict[myList[nextMethodIndex]];
         console.log("Next method:", myList[nextMethodIndex]);
         nextMethodIndex++;
         console.log("TimeOut:", parseInt(query.TimeOut));
         setTimeout(func, parseInt(query.TimeOut, 10));
    }
}
```

`myList` is along the lines of `var methodOrder=['first', 'second', 'third']` and `myDict` like:

```
var myDict={
  'first':first,
  'second':second,
  'third':third
}
```

`console.log("TimeOut:", parseInt(query.TimeOut, 10));` prints the value of `TimeOut` just fine. However, `setTimeout(func, parseInt(query.TimeOut, 10));` fails on the second run with the following:

```
     console.log("TimeOut:", parseInt(query.TimeOut, 10));
                                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'TimeOut' of undefined
    at runNextMethod (/home/root/r1_server.js:94:48)
    at initI2C [as _onTimeout] (/home/root/r1_server.js:111:3)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

Why? How can it read the value a line higher up just fine and fail at it now?

Comment: Based on that error, it's actually failing on the `console.log()` call the second time through, not on the `setTimeout()` call. Are you sure that `query` is defined on the second call to `runNextMethod()`? What happens if you add `console.log(query);` before the offending `log()` call?

Comment: @PaulRoub `console.log(query)` prints `undefined` on the second run. I guess the real question is how to use the function in such a way the parameters stick during recursion.

Comment: @Mast How is recursion occurring here? you are calling different function from `runNextMethod`.

Comment: @hassansin That's what you get for writing MCVE. The function called ends with `runNextMethod()`. So in the end the current function gets called again, but without parameters. Just passing `query` along would work, but ends with not using the `setTimeout` because Node.JS is event driven. Using callbacks here would result in callback-hell I think.

Comment: yeah, that's the problem. when you call `runNextMethod()` at the end, your `query` is set to undefined in next call overwriting the `query` of first call.

Comment: out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve here? it seems there surely is a better way to do this.

Comment: @DanPantry There probably is a better way to do this. I'm writing a series of I2C commands. Better ideas are welcome.